# Ubuntu partition on windows formatting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I woke up today to this error:[image]

After several times restarting my computer I ended up on a window that gave me the opportunity to format my C: partition. I did it. I just finished installing windows but now I don't know what happened to my ubuntu partition. Here's what I have:[image]

Is it possible my ubuntu was in the 'Disco 0 Particion 8'? If it is, is there a way to get it back? Thanks

Comment: Windows will have messed up the Ubuntu boot files. Have a look at this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked what @PonJar said in the comments. My Ubuntu partition was indeed number 8 (sda8) and it looks like I didn't loose any data.